# How to trigger now scheduled oozie job?

Tags: scheduling, oozie, oozie-coordinator

I've submitted a job to Oozie using the following command:

```
oozie job -config ${config_file} -submit
```

My job is scheduled to run at 5 UTC every day (frequency = 1440). My question is - how to trigger an execution outside of this time range? Let's say I've submitted a job @ 7 UTC but don't want to wait till the next day 5 UTC and want to trigger it right away manually after submission.

I've tried to start a job:

```
oozie job -oozie host -start coordinatior-job-id-C
```

But got:

```
Error: E0303 : E0303: Invalid parameter value, [action] = [start]
```

Properties file content:

```
nameNode=hdfs://<namenode>:8020
jobTracker=http://<namenode>:23140
queueName=root.oozie
user=${user.name}
oozie.libpath=/user/oozie/share/lib
oozie.use.system.libpath=true
oozie.coord.application.path=${nameNode}/user/${user.name}/<job.location>
appPath=${oozie.coord.application.path}
initTime=2020-04-20T00:15Z
interval=0
frequency=1440
start=2020-04-20T00:50Z
oozie.launcher.mapreduce.map.cpu.vcores=1
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The below command should work unless there are valid configurations:

```
oozie job -oozie <oozie_host> -start <workflow_id>
```

Note: A coordinator job does not support the start action.

Please provide job files in case of errors.

Comment: This is a coordinator job I'm trying to start. Inside coordinator job there are coordinator actions - how can I trigger that coordinator action?

Comment: Job actions should be in workflow file. Please provide the coordinator, workflow and properties files.

Comment: Please provide coordinator file.